# Codename One unable to see local notification on Netbeans debugger

Tags: netbeans, codenameone, uilocalnotification

I am using Local Notifications in my app.

The notification are firing when the app is installed, but not when I use the NetBeans debugger.

My hunch is that for the notifications to work the app has to be running in the background" of a real phone.

I wonder if there is a way to see the the Local Notifications when using a debugger ....

Many thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local Notification is platform specific and is not supported on simulator.
So, you can't see a local notification on a simulator at the moment.

In future, I will like to see a code like below added to the simulator for local notification on Desktop, using Timer event while the simulator is still open:

```
SystemTray sysTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
TrayIcon tray = new TrayIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(pathToIcon));
tray.setImageAutoSize(true);
try {
    sysTray.add(tray);
    tray.displayMessage(title, message, TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have just added support for LocalNotifications in the simulator, using this code as a basis.  It will be available in the next update.

Comment: Great work Steve, I'm actually currently working on it. Good that you beat me to that :). Thank you.